# nextProps.history.push is not re rendering the component upon login

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a high order component that redirects user to dashboard upon signing in. The issue is the dashboard is not being re rendered upon redirect.

```
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
        nextProps.history.push("/dashboard");

      }
      if (nextProps.errors) {
        return { errors: nextProps.errors };
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Would anyone know what the issue could be ? I am using hash router by the way

**isAuthenticated(FullCode)**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {  initLogin } from "../../actions/userActions";

export interface authHocProps {
  user?: any;
  history?: any;
  initLogin: () => void;
}
export interface authState {
  errors: object;
}
export default function(WrappedComponent) {
  class IsAuth extends Component<authHocProps, authState> {
    //   this line is magic, redirects to the dashboard after user signs up
    // this replace getDerivedStateFromPropss
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
      if (nextProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
        nextProps.history.push("/dashboard");

      }
      if (nextProps.errors) {
        return { errors: nextProps.errors };
      }
      return null;
    }
    ourState: authState = {
      errors: {},
    };
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.initLogin();
      if (this.props.user.isAuthenticated) {
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
      }

    }
    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
    user: state.user,
  });
  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
    initLogin: () => dispatch(initLogin()),
  });
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IsAuth);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your issue might be due to the fact that you are attempting to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` for something other than its intended use. Based on the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops), it seems like this is not the place for side effects, but rather the goal is to return an object to update state. Even tho looking at your code I can't say for sure that I know why it's not working, I do think that by using the correct life cycle method you may very well solve your issue.

I think `componentDidUpdate` would be the correct life cycle method to use here and it would look a little something like this.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.user.isAuthenticated) {
        prevProps.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, this solution changes the nav state but does not redirect to dashboard.

Comment: could be that be due to the fact you are using hash router? I have never used hash router before, but do you need include the hash in your route?

Comment: Should i be using hash router just as i would use router ?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix it by doing this, thanks @Chaim for me in the right direction

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  if(prevProps.user.isAuthenticated !== this.props.user.isAuthenticated){
    this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
  }
  if (prevProps.errors) {
    this.setState({
      errors: prevProps.errors
    })
  }

}
```

Also by using `<Router>` Instead of `<HashRouter>`